# Apollonian network and 4 coloring

Tags: graph-theory

Is there a connection between the Apollonian network and the four-color theorem? Are there any attempts to prove this theorem using the Apollonian network?

Comment: From https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniquely_colorable_graph : The uniquely 4-colorable planar graphs are known to be exactly the Apollonian networks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Wikipedia's article on [Apollonian networks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apollonian_network#History) mentions, "*Birkhoff (1930) is an early paper that uses a dual form of Apollonian networks, the planar maps formed by repeatedly placing new regions at the vertices of simpler maps, as a class of examples of planar maps with few colorings.*" This refers to [Birkhoff, On the number of ways of colouring a map](https://www.semanticscholar.org/paper/On-the-Number-of-Ways-of-Colouring-a-Map-Birkhoff/82f319da4ed2539f3a53cdd5f9cca0c9352e8600).

More recently, Fowler proved in his [PhD thesis Unique Coloring of Planar Graphs (1998)](https://people.math.gatech.edu/~thomas/FC/fowlerphd.pdf) that every uniquely 4-colorable graph is an Apollonian network, and the Four Color theorem follows from this. Curiously, he does not cite Birkhoff's 1930 paper and does not use the name "Apollonian network". See [Brændeland's Color fixation, color identity
 and the Four Color Theorem](https://arxiv.org/abs/1405.1323) for a different take on Fowler's theorem.